# comparing number from CSV file to 2 values in python

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to compare a number stored in a CSV file with 2 numbers as you can see below.

The problem is I’m unable to compare it to other numbers without adding ' ' around it which is not working in this way.

```
file =  open('data.csv' , 'r')
reader = csv.reader(file)
for row in reader: 
    if  '1400' <= row[0] <= '1920' and '50' <= row[1] <=  '120' :
```

As I think the numbers are stored as a string in the CSV file if I’m not mistaken, and I need to convert this numbers to integer or double to be able to use it in the way I intended to, any kind of help would be awesome and sorry if it is a stupid question to ask.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV is a text format, so any data read from a CSV file is read as text.  You need to convert the text to the appropriate type of data for use in your program.

You can compare strings, in Python, using the `<=` operator.  However, it performs a *text* comparison, such as you would use when alphabetizing a list.  It is *not* a numerical comparison.

Ignoring the need for error handling, you can correct your code like this:

```
for row in reader: 
    if  1400 <= int(row[0]) <= 1920 and 50 <= int(row[1]) <= 120 :
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert strings to integers by wrapping it in the int() function. So you would have something like:

```
if  1400 <= int(row[0])...
```

In the future, try searching on Google for something like "Convert string to int python," and you'll get an answer much quicker :)